# WPF Image control decimates large bitmaps

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing an image viewer application that loads large still images. I must be able to zoom in to 1:1 to measure exact pixel coordinates of features in the image. I'm using the Viewport control posted here that works great for zoom and panning. I can load a 150 MP tiff image with BitmapDecoder and its pixel count is correct 14000 x 10000. However, when I assign this bitmap to the Image.Source property it gets decimated to roughly 15MP:

sourceBitmap.PixelWidth = 14204

sourceBitmap.PixelHeight = 10652

After assigning this bitmap to image1.Source we get

image1.Source.Width = 4545.27...

image1.Source.Height = 3408.64...

I'm aware of the unitless context of WPF graphics, and can work back the scale factors to read original coordinates, but there is a risk of rounding errors, and I'm working on a scaled copy that degrades the original image resolution. 
According to the Microsoft documentation, a WPF bitmap can be up to 64GB in size, but the Image control seems not to be designed to work with bitmaps larger than 15MP. Setting Stretch to "None" makes things worst. It trims the image to the top left 4545 x 3408 pixels of the source and it displays it very small, almost as a thumbnail instead of 1:1.

Is there any way around this limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrast to a BitmapSource's `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight`, the `Width`and `Height` values depend on its DPI (dots per inch), which is a TIFF or EXIF tag in the image file.

The values are identical when the resolution is 96 DPI, otherwise calculated as

```
Width = PixelWidth * 96 / DpiX
Height = PixelHeight * 96 / DpiY
```

Apparently, your images are tagged with 300 DPI.

This does in no way affect the pixel count, but just determines the native, unstretched size of the bitmap when it is shown in an Image element or ImageBrush.

---

Instead of using Width and Height, just keep using PixelWidth and PixelHeight:

```
var bitmap = (BitmapSource)image1.Source;
var width = bitmap.PixelWidth;
var height = bitmap.PixelHeight;
```

Comment: You are 100% correct, these images are tagged with 300DPI in the Exif metadata. Mea culpa, I read and forgot about the difference between Width and PixelWidtth, etc. The autocompletion may be your enemy sometimes!. Thank you for pointing out my error!.